# How to open Neo4J Webadmin to remote control?

Tags: neo4j, remote-access, administration

I have installed a Neo4J instance on my server on port 7474. My domain is also using that server and I want webadmin to be used remotely with a username and a password like this:

```
example.com:7474
```

Is there a way to do that? I could not find any guideline in the Neo4J documentation.

Answer (score 17):

Did you get a chance to go through [Neo4j Server Configuration documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-configuration.html)? It says:

> #allow any client to connect
>
> org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

This line in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` is commented by default and limits access to port `7474` to localhost or `127.0.0.1` (which probably is the reason why things work for your domain using that server and accessing Neo4j over localhost). Uncomment that line and it should make port 7474 accessible to everyone i.e. `0.0.0.0`.

In order to secure your Neo4j server with an Authorization layer, you might want to refer [Securing access to the Neo4j Server documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html).

Answer (score 4):

In my case on ubuntu the line to uncomment was

```
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
```

File location

```
Ubuntu: /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
```

Neo4j 3.0.6