# Setting up Azure VM for Neo4j (or any local database)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to run Neo4j in an Azure VM. I created the VM, remoted in, and installed Neo. Neo uses a default port of :7474. I can see the database running with Remote Desktop and localhost:7474.

I can't however, connect to it from another machine. I created an Endpoint in Azure with private and public ports of 7474, but when I go to it in my browser - http://eurlexgraphvm.cloudapp.net:7474/ there's nothing there.

Am I missing a step that allows incoming requests to see the locally running database?

Comment: This has been answered in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705451/how-to-open-neo4j-webadmin-to-remote-control

Comment: I have changed this setting in the neo config, but it hasn't made a difference. Perhaps I need to change a firewall setting on the Azure VM?

Comment: There are no initial firewall blocks set when you spin up an Azure VM. If you map an endpoint to port 7474, you're going to have access to port 7474 (unless you apply an IP-filtering ACL). One curious thing though: You mentioned 'remoting' in - are you using Windows for this server? I don't know if the Windows version runs as a service (I thought you had to launch it manually; I run it in Linux exclusively).